# this._setInputValue is not a function

Tags: lightning, error-messages

getting a strange issue on a Lightning page.  In the background, I'm trying to update a Long Text Area field with Apex (before update trigger) but it seems to throw this error whenever I try to update the value of that field.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a JS issue or a handler issue. Would you able to post the relevant code?

Comment: That's the confusing part @manjit5190 - this is a standard layout, so no JS code written on our end.  I submitted a case to Salesforce and apparently they have a few reports of this

Comment: Do you have the debug mode turned on for lightning and if you disable the trigger does it works fine?

Comment: Correct, I started disabling everything in the trigger and got it down to one line: when I update the value of the Long Text area.

And yes, lightning debugger shows the same error and stack trace.

Comment: We're also having the same issue.  Up-voting this question, hopefully someone has more insight as-to what the solution may be.  (Thinking it's an issue on the SFDC core)

Comment: We've also been experiencing this. It seems an update to Chrome has rectified this error.

Comment: Does an error occur when you update the field in Classic UI?

Comment: To everyone who has found this issue question through search, *welcome to SFSE*! Please *do not* post an answer to indicate that you are also affected. Post an answer only if you are able to offer a solution to this problem.

Comment: Update to chrome did not rectify the error.
When doing the same update in Classic UI, no error occurs.

Comment: This [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003vbtQAA) mentions the same error, but the description is sparse and just says to contact support

Comment: As linked in Kris's comment above - that "Known Issue" was provided to me in response to my support Case submitted with SFDC. Their response stated: This issue is already being reviewed by our Internal Team and was submitted as known issue. Please kindly visit the link below and click on the button "This issue affects me" to add on their report. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003vbtQAA

Comment: Looks like this is a widespread issue now. Is this correct understanding that this issue is happening with Inline Edit as well as Edit Modal window in Lightning Experience? I am not able to replicate it myself, but some of our users have this issue, they mostly do inline edits. Also, I believe there is no workaround in place other than refreshing the screen, is this safe to assume? Thanks in advance .

Comment: The description of that KI doesn't really make any sense, though, does it? 1) I never ever heard of creating List Views not related to a specific sObject - how would you even do that? 2) How does that relate to this error? Inline editing or something?

Comment: @ThomasTaylor apparently there are two slightly different issues, the other is here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003vbyQAA

Comment: So my user is getting this error, but we are not editing with Apex nor editing through a list view. My user is just editing a custom Long Text field on the opportunity. I've added myself to both known issues, but is my case different? This only started showing up in the last day or so. No changes to the Opp.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else noted, this is a known issue - apparently this is scheduled to be fixed by April 21, 2020 (that's what they told me in my Salesforce Case).

For the time being, the workaround I'm using is to change the Long Text Area field to a Rich Text field, it seems to have resolved the issue.